# player position is out of sync audio_service flutter

Tags: just-audio, audio-service

I have an audioplayer application which uses `audio_service` and `just_audio` plugins for playback. Everything seems fine but there are 2 issues that I am facing.

1. The player position is out of sync, the duration becomes the position but when I pause the audio it reflects the right position. This behaviour can be seen on the notifications and on the `AudioService.positionStream` which is updating the seek bar on Flutter UI.
2. Audio stops playing on lock screen out of the blue.
   [image: position while playing is same as duration]

[image: position when pause]

My code:

```
_playbackSubscription = _player.playbackEventStream.listen((event) {
     setState(_player, event);
   });

 void setState(AudioPlayer _player, event) {
   if (queue == null || queue.isEmpty) return;
   var controls = [
     MediaControl.skipToPrevious,
     _player.playing ? MediaControl.pause : MediaControl.play,
     MediaControl.skipToNext,
     MediaControl.stop
   ];
   AudioServiceBackground.setMediaItem(
       queue.elementAt(_player.currentIndex).copyWith(
             duration: _player.duration,
           ));
   AudioServiceBackground.setState(
       playing: _player.playing,
       bufferedPosition: _player.bufferedPosition,
       speed: _player.speed,
       shuffleMode: _player.shuffleModeEnabled
           ? AudioServiceShuffleMode.all
           : AudioServiceShuffleMode.none,
       repeatMode:
           AudioServiceRepeatMode.values.elementAt(_player.loopMode.index),
       position: _player.position,
       processingState: {
         ProcessingState.idle: AudioProcessingState.none,
         ProcessingState.loading: AudioProcessingState.connecting,
         ProcessingState.buffering: AudioProcessingState.buffering,
         ProcessingState.ready: AudioProcessingState.ready,
         ProcessingState.completed: AudioProcessingState.completed,
       }[_player.processingState],
       systemActions: [
         MediaAction.seekBackward,
         MediaAction.seekTo,
         MediaAction.seekForward
       ],
       controls: controls,
       updateTime: event?.updateTime ?? DateTime.now());
 }
```

Code Block Summary: Basically setting the `AudioService` state whenever the player state changes.

Comment: 1. What version of just_audio are you using? I suspect that the value of `playing` isn't what you expect because `playbackEventStream` does not include the `playing` value (try logging these values to ensure they are as expected). It's an easy thing to miss, so the latest versions of just_audio will actually emit a dud event on `playbackEventStream` when the `playing` state changes, as a safetynet for when the programmer doesn't explicitly listen to `playing` state changes.
2. Maybe you're streaming audio over the net, but Android decided to activate power-saving mode and disable wifi.

Comment: ```audio_service: version: "0.17.1", just_audio : version: "0.8.0"```, I am streaming  audio from net and I checked there’s no power saving mode enabled. It's just while playing the progress bar is progressing per second but when I pause the audio, the position is different from the progress.

Comment: Did you try logging the `playing`, `position` and `processingState` values inside `setState`? That would reveal which value is not as expected.

Comment: yes, I tried logging them, and they are fine whenever the player state gets changed.
The real issue comes when the player is playing and the position starts getting overlapping the duration or just doesn’t sync with the audio

Comment: But that issue would have been revealed in the logs. When the issue happens, what do the logs say?

Comment: I put the logs in the playerEventStream, as you told me, and the stream only updates when there's an event performed on the player. While the player is playing I get the log ```ProcessingState.ready``` and then it doesn't log until I pause/stop the player.

Comment: you can check the logic here, It has both UI handler and the background 
 audio task class, https://gist.github.com/Jagrajsinghji/cdfe7b69e4674dc63743704c83de5a44

Comment: That gist contains dart code, not a log. That said, I can see in your code what you're logging and you've left out the event's update position. Can you also log `event.updatePosition`? It maybe easier to read the log if you print out all information on one line so that each line represents a separate event.

Comment: ```Player Playing :  true at position 0:00:55.829000
flutter: Event State: ProcessingState.buffering , Duration 0:16:09.000000, Update Position0:00:55.829000``` The first position is the player position and the later is coming from event.

Comment: You can check logs here, the position changes to real position of player whenever I pause the audio. https://ibb.co/wST2rL6 Otherwise it's just increasing without sync

Comment: In that clipped fragment of the log, it only shows the one event that actually has no issue (i.e. the pause event, which as you said, works fine). You should want to look at the preceding play event which led to the position being wrong. We should try not to go back and forth in the comments section for too long.

Comment: just a single play event and then a pause event is performed, I am saying that the actual issue is with playerPositionStream not with the playerEventStream. Can we talk on discord or somewhere else, I need to publish a new version of my app.

Comment: If there is a bug with playerPositionStream, you can submit a bug report instead (but I can tell you that if there is a bug, it's more likely to be in the playback events.). It sounds like you don't want to provide the complete logs of the events here, but if you submit a bug report, it will require you to provide all necessary information to investigate the issue.

Comment: I don’t know what exactly you need in the logs, I have provided what you asked. The gist contains all the working code, so you can tell me what in logs do you need to process the issue.

Comment: Your code is printing out the right values, but you need to look at the whole log in context to find where it has gone wrong. When you share only a fragment of the log that shows things working normally, that doesn't provide any clues whatsoever, as I tried to explain above. Anyway, this will be my last comment here, since the question does not have enough information to answer it, back-and-forth comments should be avoided. If you think you've found a bug, you would be better off submitting a bug report.